# Exponential and Mobius function

Tags: calculus

In Cohen book, there is this exercise. No hint is given. Prove that (formally)
$e^x=\prod_{n\ge1}(1-x^n)^{\mu(n)/n}$ where $\mu$ is the Mobius function. Any solution would be welcome.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot a minus sign. For $|x| < 1$ where everything converges absolutely
$$\log \prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-x^n)^{-\mu(n)/n}= -\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \log(1-x^n) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{n}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^{nk}}{k} \\= \sum_{m=1}^\infty x^m \sum_{m= nk} \frac{1}{k} \frac{\mu(n)}{n}=\sum_{m=1}^\infty x^m\frac{1}{m} \sum_{d | m} \mu(d) = \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{x^m}{m} 1_{m = 1} = x $$

Where I used the Taylor series for $-\log(1-x)$ and the defining property of the Möbius function $\sum_{d | m} \mu(d) = 1_{m=1}$.